# How to parse Complex JSON data of spreadsheet in android?

Tags: android, json, google-sheets

I am new to android, As I am trying to parse the Google's spreadsheet data and it is somewhat complex to me, I have to fetch $t of gsx$tag and $t of gsx$datetime,

This is the link from which we can get the JSON data 
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1_AR0zX6Jv0NI_R1HBULbPEIUuJ2mqVbLoHVvLqOwu1I/1/public/values?alt=json

Data look like this

```
{  
"version":"1.0",
"encoding":"UTF-8",      
 "feed":{  
  "xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
  "xmlns$openSearch":"http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/",
  "xmlns$gsx":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended",
  "id":{  },

  "updated":{  },
  "category":[  ],
  "title":{  },
  "link":[  ],
  "author":[  ],
  "openSearch$totalResults":{  },
  "openSearch$startIndex":{  },
  "entry":[  
     {  
        "id":{  },
        "updated":{  },
        "category":[  ],
        "title":{  },
        "content":{  },
        "link":[  ],
        "gsx$id":{  
           "$t":"1"
        },
        "gsx$datetime":{  
           "$t":"3/28/2017"
        },
        "gsx$tag":{  
           "$t":"21"
        }
     },
  { Data here },
  { Data here }
  ]
  }
  }
```

and below is the code I am trying

```
HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                Log.e(TAG,"JSon Data"+mainObj);
                if (mainObj != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"JSon before feed"+mainObj.toString());
                    JSONArray a = mainObj.getJSONArray("feed");
                    Log.e(TAG,"JSon after feed"+a.toString());
                    JSONObject entru= new JSONObject((Map) a);
                    JSONArray list = entru.getJSONArray("entry");
  //                       JSONArray entryarray = list.getJSONArray("entry");
                    if (list != null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject elem = list.getJSONObject(i);
                            if (elem != null) {
                                JSONArray prods = elem.getJSONArray("gsx$tag");
                                if (prods != null) {
                                    for (int j = 0; j < prods.length(); j++) {

                                        JSONObject innerElem = prods.getJSONObject(j);
                                        if (innerElem != null) {
                                            String sku = innerElem.getString("$t");
                                            Log.e(TAG, "$t" + sku);
                                            HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                                            contact.put("$t Datetime", sku);

                                            // adding contact to contact list
                                            contactList.add(contact);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Help Me in this regards, Thank you in advance

Comment: check my answer below and try

Comment: I updated my answer and put full code. Please check if it is helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONArray a = mainObj.getJSONArray("feed");
Log.e(TAG,"JSon after feed"+a.toString());
JSONObject entru= new JSONObject((Map) a);
```

replace this 3 lines with the below one

```
 JSONObject entru= mainObj.getJSONObject("feed");
```

also replace this line

```
JSONArray prods = elem.getJSONArray("gsx$tag");
```

with this one

```
 JSONObject prods = elem.getJSONObject("gsx$tag");
```

I think this is the correct code.

```
HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
    // Making a request to url and getting response
    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

    Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            Log.e(TAG,"JSon Data"+mainObj);
            if (mainObj != null) {
                Log.e(TAG,"JSon before feed"+mainObj.toString());
                JSONObject entru= mainObj.getJSONObject("feed");
                JSONArray list = entru.getJSONArray("entry");
  //JSONArray entryarray = list.getJSONArray("entry");
                if (list != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject elem = list.getJSONObject(i);
                        if (elem != null) {
                            JSONObject prods = elem.getJSONObject("gsx$tag");
                            if (prods != null) {
                                for (int j = 0; j < prods.length(); j++) {


                                        String sku = prods.getString("$t");
                                        Log.e(TAG, "$t" + sku);
                                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                                        contact.put("$t Datetime", sku);

                                        // adding contact to contact list
                                        contactList.add(contact);

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Please try this. If this doesn't work please feel free to ask. will help you

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have accepted your answer as the final one

Comment: Welcome. Happy to help you :) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)